# Rails 3.1.11 Assets Precompilation sprockets not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, production-environment, precompile

Rails 3.1.11 Assets Precompilation not working for images, css and js as for css and js it calls every file and increases loading time and for images it does not getting images from there compiled path.

I ran following command to precompile assets:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

and it made assets directory under public directory of my app,
and created images loading-91e9fa95ae55553f2c46cbfa9a9940de.gif like this but when I try to get these images its not loading a single image from the path. I'm using image_tag shown below

```
 <%= image_tag('theme_images/img/gemicon/edit.png') %>
```

and its source image path is 'app_root/public/assets/theme_images/img/gemicon/edit.png'.